# Post with AngularJS doesn't work

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, post

I would like to send a post request to my API. It works with jQuery :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "api.php?option=inscription",
  data: {lol : "mess"}
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't with AngularJS :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">    </script>
{{1+1}}
<script>
$http.post('api.php?option=inscription', {lol : "mess2"})
.success(function(){alert('cool');});
</script>
```

If someone can help me. Thank you !

UPDATE :
Thank for your answers, I wanted to simplify but it wasn't clear anymore. So with your help, this is my new code, and the problem is the same. The data in the backend is empty ;

frontend :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">   </script>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
{{data}}

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('SomeService', function($http) {
this.readData = function(dataUrl, dataTobePosted) {

    var back =  $http.post(dataUrl, dataTobePosted);

    back.success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      return status;
});
    }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, SomeService){
$scope.readData = function(url) {
    var dataTobePosted = {"lol": "mess"};

    $scope.data = SomeService.readData(url, dataTobePosted);
}

$scope.readData('api.php?option=inscription');
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you injected $http in the controller ? @LekimR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my problem came from my backend in the php I just get my data with :

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

and not with $_POST

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, I am suggesting a simple implementation. However, further reading may needed in order to understand the behaviour precisely.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('SomeService', function($http) {
    this.readData = function(dataUrl, dataTobePosted) {
        // read data;
        return $http.post(dataUrl, dataTobePosted)
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            }, function(res) {
                return res;
            }
    }
    return this;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope, SomeService) {
    $scope.readData = function(url) {
        var dataTobePosted = {"lol": "mess"};

        SomeService.readData(url, dataTobePosted)
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.data = res;
        }, function(res) {
            // Display error
        }
    }

    $scope.readData('api.php?option=inscription');
}
```

Usage in the HTML page

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using AngularJS as if it's jQuery. It's not. AngularJS works with dependency injection, so you need to wrap your $http call inside a controller.

You should probably read up on AngularJS. A few useful links:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di
- ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1)